# socket.end() can't close connection without first parameter [data] in electron

Tags: node.js, electron

I am using nodejs net module in electron and getting some troubles

1. when I use socket.end() outside the socket event callback, it's not working.But if inside the callback like

```
socket.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log(data.toString())
        socket.end()
    })
```

it works just fine.

2. Outside the socket event callback, if I use first parameter like this:

```
 socket.end('')
```

it works.But if I write like this:

```
 socket.end()
```

the connection cannot be closed and no warning or error.

I am confused beause when I use `socket.end()` just in nodejs environment only (without electron),it works again.

Can anybody help me figure out why it behaves differently ?